# What we can do if the inverse of our function can not be determined explicitly

Tags: real-analysis, functions, trigonometry

My question is a little bit general: what we can do if the inverse of our function can not be founded explicitly?

For example, let consider the function $$f(x)=x \cos (x)\quad\quad \quad\mbox{ for }\;x\in [0, \frac12]$$
this function is clearly invertible on $[0, \frac12]$, but we can not have an explicit formula of the inverse (you can try !).

Let $y \in f([0, \frac12])$; Is there any approximation or something to do to have an expression of $y$ such that $$x=f^{-1}(y)$$

Comment: thanks, yes the inverse of the  values can be determined, but I speak about the function in the hull interval

Comment: How accurate do you want the approximation to be?

Comment: In certain cases, you can determine the series expansion of the inverse function. An archetypal example is the inverse of $f(x)=xe^x$ around the origin, in which the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) gives a very neat formula for the Taylor series of the inverse of $f$ around the origin.

Comment: @Andrei the best possible approximation you can obtain but not only for this function in a general case. as the answer of Sangchul Lee but this is just in a neighborhood of  a point

Comment: @user745750 That's a very general problem. For this particular case I would write the Taylor series around $0$: $f(x)\approx x-x^3/2=y$, then use the formula for cubic equation to find $f^{-1}(y)=x(y)$. Alternatively, you can find a numeric solution for $f(x)-y=0$ for a given $y$. Newton's method would probably work fine.

Comment: There is no general answer, because this depends on why exactly you need the inverse function.

Comment: [Very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087779/solve-y-x-cosx-for-x/4534268#4534268) except for the general title of this one

Answer (score 2):

$$y=x \cos (x)\quad\quad \quad\mbox{ for }\;x\in [0, \frac12]$$

The function is so linear that Taylor series built around $x=0$ is very tempting. now, using series reversion
$$x=y+\frac{y^3}{2}+\frac{17 y^5}{24}+\frac{961 y^7}{720}+\frac{116129
   y^9}{40320}+\frac{3488503 y^{11}}{518400}+\frac{7935695921
   y^{13}}{479001600}+O\left (y^{15} \right)$$ is almost at the level of machine $\epsilon$.

If we use the expansion of $x$ up to $O\left (y^{2n+1} \right)$ in $y-x \cos(x)$, the result is $O\left (y^{2n+3} \right)$.

Similarly, if $T_n$ is the Taylor expansion of $x \cos(x)$ to $O\left (x^{2n+1} \right)$, computing the norm
$$\Phi_n=\int_0^{\frac 12} \big[x \cos(x)-T_n\big]^2\,dx$$ we have the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \log(\Phi_n) \\
 0 & -8.2167 \\
 1 & -16.393 \\
 2 & -26.272 \\
 3 & -37.328 \\
 4 & -49.290 \\
 5 & -61.988 \\
 6 & -75.306 \\
 7 & -89.161 \\
 8 & -103.49 \\
 9 & -118.24 \\
 10 & -133.37
\end{array}
\right)$$